# Terraform failing with Invalid for_each argument / The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable

Tags: foreach, terraform

When running `terraform plan` or `terraform apply` with a list provided to `for_each` an error occurs saying

```
Error: Invalid for_each argument

  on main.tf line 2, in resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo":
  2:   for_each = ["a", "b"]

The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument
must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.
```

A minimum example to reproduce this error is this:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  for_each = ["a", "b"]

  name  = "foo-${each.value}"
  type  = "String"
  value = "bar-${each.value}"
}
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

### Explanation

This error is often caused by passing a list to `for_each`, but `for_each` only works with unordered data-types, i.e. with sets and maps.

## Solution

The resolution depends on the situation.

### List of strings

If the list is just a list of strings, the easiest fix is to add a `toset()`-call to transform the list to a set that can be handled by for_each, like this

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  for_each = toset(["a", "b"])

  name  = "foo-${each.value}"
  type  = "String"
  value = "bar-${each.value}"
}
```

### List that can be rearranged to a map

If the input is a list, but easily be rearranged to a map this is usually the best way.
Say we have a list like this

```
locals {
  animals = [
    {
      name = "Bello"
      age = 3
      type = "dog"
    },
    {
      name = "Minga"
      age = 4
      type = "cat"
    },
  ]
}
```

Then an appropriate re-structuring might be this

```
locals {
  animals = {
    Bello : {
      age = 3
      type = "dog"
    },
    Minga : {
      age = 4
      type = "cat"
    }
  }
}
```

which then allows you to define

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  for_each = local.animals

  name  = each.key
  type  = string
  value = "This is a ${each.value.type}, ${each.value.age} years old."
}
```

### List that you do not want to rearrange

Sometimes it is natural to have a list, e.g. comming from an output of a module that one does not control or from a resource that is defined with `count`. In such a situation, one can either work with count like this

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  count = length(local.my_list)

  name  = my_list[count.index].name
  type  = "String"
  value = my_list[count.index].value
}
```

which works for a list of maps containing name and value as keys. Often times, though, it is more appropriate to transform the list to a map instead like this

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  for_each = { for x in local.my_list: x.id => x }

  name  = each.value.name
  type  = "String"
  value = each.value.value
}
```

Here one should choose anything appropriate in place of `x.id`. If `my_list` is a list of objects, there is usually some common field like a name or key, that can be used. The advantage of this approach in favor of using `count` as above, is that this behaves better when inserting or removing elements from the list. `count` will not notice the insertion or deletion as such and will hence update all resources following the place where the insertion took place, while `for_each` really only adds or removes the resource with the new or deleted id.

Comment: I would correct that the error is not "caused by passing a list to for_each", but because the `for_each` only works with unordered data types. A list is an ordered type, a set or a map are not.

Comment: this is very strange, you could a list of map inside the dynamic block, but if you use the for_each outside you get the error :(

Comment: I agree; this is bizarre.  If the language is capable of iterating over an unordered collection, what in the world could possibly preclude iteration over an ordered collection?  Terraform fails the Law of Least Astonishment.

Comment: Does it really has something to do with ordered vs. unordered data type? I always thought that list are simply not possible because there could be duplicate elements in a list (whereas a set can only have unique values) which could result in multiple resources with the exact same name (which is not allowed in terraform).

Comment: I've found that using `setunion()` is usually enough for TF to iterate over an array and let go of that "unordered" requirement